# Is it possible to configure multiple RabbitMQ configuration based on externalised config through Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I could see that we can easily configure a single RabbitMQ through externalized config in Spring-Boot so that it automatically starts up when boot application get started.

I want to know if there is a way we can configure multiple RabbitMQs in the same applications using externalized config through Spring Boot?

Any hints?

Comment: You want multiple RabbitMQ brokers in your application? Isn't that a bit unusual?

Comment: Yes, I want multiple RabbitMQ brokers. It might look unusual but as per our requirements and system design, we do need multiple brokers. Do you have a way to do that using spring-boot?